# How could I add conditional link colour to my wordpress site that depends on the purpose of the hyperlink?

Tags: links, formatting

I'm using a plugin called Encyclopedia/Wiki/Glossary to automatically hyperlink all instances of words that have been defined in the glossary directory so that they will be linked anywhere they appear on the site. But I want the links to be styled differently than the default link style so it's clear these links are for definitions (as people will mostly use the tooltip which comes up on hover) and not for external links or other non-glossary pages. Is there a way to do this e.g by styling the link if it contains the slug /glossary/ or would it have to be done via the plugin.

Comment: Depends if this plugin A) adds a class to the links or B) allows you to somehow specify that these links need their own unique class.  Without some sort of identifier added to the links you really don't have a method of targeting them. I'd recommend reaching out to the plugin dev and if it's not something it currently does, request that they add it in a future release/update.

Comment: Thank you very much tony